# How to write a Function where you can both include an argument as an input or request it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function

[image]I have a function where an argument is passed in as follows:

```
def Q_Avg1(Ticker):

    stock = web.DataReader(Ticker, 'iex', start, end)  # Daily time series
    stock.index = pd.to_datetime(stock.index)  # index is the date
    stock_q = stock['close'].resample('Q').mean()
    x = round(stock_q, 2)

    return x
```

I simply type in Q_Avg1('MSFT') and presto.

I also have another where you are prompted for the ticker..

```
def Q_Avg2():

    Ticker = str(input('Enter Ticker (without quotes): '))
    stock = web.DataReader(Ticker, 'iex', start, end)  # Daily time series
    stock.index = pd.to_datetime(stock.index)  # index is the date
    stock_q = stock['close'].resample('Q').mean()

    x = round(stock_q, 2)

    return x
```

When I type in A_Avg2(): it prompts to enter the ticker and i get the same result.

My question is how I could set this up as one function where if I pass an argument (the ticker) it works but if I don't put anything in it prompts me like in the second version.  I was trying something like if Ticker != '' but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put Ticker with default argument as object, So if u passed object it will take as parameter and if you dont pass it will simple take default one
Example:-

```
def Q_Avg2(Ticker=None): 
    if Ticker is None:
        Ticker = str(input('Enter Ticker (without quotes)')) 
    stock = web.DataReader(Ticker, 'iex', start, end)  # Daily time series
    stock.index = pd.to_datetime(stock.index)  # index is the date
    stock_q = stock['close'].resample('Q').mean()

    x = round(stock_q, 2)

    return x
```

Q_Avg2()

You can call function with or without arguments

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it but get errors.  By using  If Ticker == None: it says invalid syntax and suggests I use "if cond is None:"  When I try that (If Ticker is None:)  I get another type of invalid syntax with no explanation.

Comment: make sure the indentation is correct, the sample code provided is not properly written (ticker = str(input...) should have proper indentation)

Comment: Just edited  if condition. Yes please do follow indentation as well.

Comment: for some reason I still get the error. And I have been very careful with the indentation.  Using Spyder which forces me to.  The line "If Ticker is None:" gives me an invalid syntax error. same in the ipython line 11 If Ticker is None:         
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I just posted a screenshot of my code as part of the initial question.

Comment: Hey Chris, its  Capital letter 'I' in 'If'. I have changed the code, it's working. corrected indentation as well.